# how post nested array json objects relationships

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm trying to post a service json with nested array json objects relationships todos. When I do that, app shows me next error:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

This is my model class:

```
const serviceSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  subject: String,
  pricePerHour: Number,
  relatedTodos: 
    [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
   ref:'todos'}],
 createdAt: Date,
 updatedAt: Date
});
```

This is my post route:

```
app.post('/api/services', async (req, res) => {

  const { name, subject, pricePerHour} = req.body;

  let todos = await Service.findById(req.params.id).TODO.find({});

  if (!todos) {
   return res.status(404).json({
     message: "todos couldn't be found"
    });
  }

  const service = new Service({
   name,
   description,
   pricePerHour,
   relatedTodos

  })


  try {
   let newService = await service.save(); 

   res.status(201).send(newService); 
  } catch (err) {
   if (err.name === 'MongoError') {
  res.status(409).send(err.message);
   }

    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
});
```

How can I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `req.params.id` how you are getting this there is no param in your req and what is TODO ? .Please provide complete info to get help .Thanks

Comment: I could already. Don't worry. I was declaring an unexisting object.